# My function is returning None, even if I've declared a return statement

Tags: python, pandas, exception

I've created a code based on selenium. 
I'm looping through pages, and when it is checked that there are no more pages left, I'm breaking the function loop with a final return statement. 
However, my final return returns None, which I've checked in my debugging process that the final object is not None. 
Please refer to the !!! in the code comments below. 
I really appreciate all your help in advance. Thanks.

```
def operate_pages(total_companies: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    current_page_companies = get_current_page_companies()
    total_companies = total_companies.append(current_page_companies)
    try:
        click_next_page()
    except NoMorePagesException:
        print("There are no more pages left")
        print(total_companies)
        # !!! Here, total_companies is a dataframe with data which I've expected. (Checked by debugging)
        return total_companies
    operate_pages(total_companies)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    initial_search()

    total_companies = pd.DataFrame()
    total_companies = operate_pages(total_companies) # !!! This returns None

    total_companies.to_csv(CSV_PATH, index=False) # Error since total_companies is None.

    print("DONE!!!")
```

Comment: This is NOT a good candidate for recursion, and recursion is the root cause of your problem.  Your innermost call will hit the exception and return, but that will return to the final statement in the previous call, which throws away that value and returns None.  You should do this iteratively, not recursively.

Comment: @TimRoberts Moving `operate_pages(total_companies)` into the `try` block would fix that, right?

Comment: No, it would not.  The SHORT term fix is to change the last line of the function to `return operate_pages(total_companies)`, but that still leaves you with a bad design.  It shouldn't be recursive.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the reply. I see that this is related to vscode showing all the recursion pages in it's callstack. Now I get the grip of it. Thanks again!